# How to join two ffmpeg commands

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, watermark

i have a script which uses this ffmpeg command's parameters for encoding videos.

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile -acodec libfaac -keyint_min 20 -r 20 -vcodec libx264 -vpre hq -crf 25 -b 300k -bt 300k -y -v 0 -bf 16 -threads 0 outputfile
```

and i have a custom command i would like to add to it, is like this

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile -vf "movie=watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]" outputfile
```

so i replaced main command like this

```
 ffmpeg -i inputfile -acodec libfaac -keyint_min 20 -r 20 -vcodec libx264 -vpre hq -crf 25 -b 300k -bt 300k -y -v 0 -bf 16 -threads 0 -vf "movie=watermark1.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]" outputfile
```

and tried it in command line, but this doesnt do anything, the output is nothing like this

```
[root@www test1]#  ffmpeg -i test1800.mp4 -acodec libfaac -keyint_min 20 -r 20 -vcodec libx264 -vpre hq -crf 25 -b 300k -bt 300k -y -v 0 -bf 16 -threads 0 -vf "movie=watermark1.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]" outputfile.mp4
[root@www test1]#
```

how do i solve this ?

Thanks for your time.

**UPDATE**
My ffmpeg command details

```
[root@www test1]# ffmpeg
ffmpeg version N-47061-gbe2c0bc Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 25 2012 09:32:08 with gcc 4.1.2 (GCC) 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264
  libavutil      52.  9.100 / 52.  9.100
  libavcodec     54. 77.100 / 54. 77.100
  libavformat    54. 37.100 / 54. 37.100
  libavdevice    54.  3.100 / 54.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 23.102 /  3. 23.102
  libswscale      2.  1.102 /  2.  1.102
  libswresample   0. 17.101 /  0. 17.101
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build of ffmpeg must be very old if you're using `-vpre` with `libx264`. Also, `-crf` and `-b` are mutually exclusive so you can either use one or the other, but not both which will result in ffmpeg ignoring one of the options.

This example is an approximation of your command, but with recent syntax:

```
ffmpeg -i input -i watermark.png -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 25 -c:a libfaac -q:a 100 -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10" output.mp4
```

If you are too lazy to compile see the [ffmpeg.org download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to Linux, Windows, or OS X builds. Note that `libfaac` will probably not be available with third-party builds, but other AAC encoders such as `libvo_aacenc` may be available--and most certainly the native encoder `aac` is always an option.

See the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for more details.

---

Some things to remember for next time:

- ffmpeg usage questions are better suited for superuser.com. Stack Overflow is specifically targeted for programming questions and answers.
- This is a common problem, but instead of saying, "this doesnt do anything" please show the complete ffmpeg console output that results from your ffmpeg command. It contains more useful information than simply stating "this doesnt do anything".
- Try to use a recent version of ffmpeg when possible. Development is very active and any encountered bugs have a good chance of already being fixed.

Comment: i have upgraded ffmpeg to the latest verion, but the script i am using is using old parameters. Thanks